# deleteById vs delete in spring jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a question about methods deleteById and delete in spring-data.
what is the difference between these methods? When should I use delete/deleteById?
I search google for one day but i have no answer for it

Comment: Functionally, they are equivalent. In fact, `SimpleJpaRepository`, the class that provides an implementation of these two methods has `void deleteById(ID id) { delete(findById(id)) }`. As apparent, `deleteById` first attempts to load an entity instance with the given identifier and then immediately invokes `delete` on the loaded instance. The only difference between `delete` and `deleteById` is that the later will throw an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` if no entity instance with the given identifier is found, whereas, the former will throw a `NullPointerException` if the instance is `null`.

Comment: @manish Can you please add relevant documentation links here?

Answer (score 13):

The method [`deleteById`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/43ff73d48514132d3d6b5624db72a3b65629b1c1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L171) will throw an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` if the supplied `id` does not exist, whereas the method [`delete`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/43ff73d48514132d3d6b5624db72a3b65629b1c1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L186) will silently return if the supplied `entity` hasn't been persisted yet, or for whatever reason it cannot be found by the `EntityManager`.

Also, as @manish noted in their comment, the method `deleteById` actually calls the `delete` method internally if the [`findById`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/43ff73d48514132d3d6b5624db72a3b65629b1c1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L267) method is able to find an entity.

Answer (score 7):

As of **`Spring-Boot 3.x`** and it's respective version of **`spring-data-jpa`**,

the method `deleteById` will **no longer** throw the Runtime exception of `EmptyResultDataAccessException` in case the provided `id` did not existed in database to be deleted.

So the only difference from now on between `deleteById(Id id)` and `delete(T entity)` is that the first one will take as parameter the `id` and try to locate the respecting entity in database with that `id` to be deleted, while the second one will take as parameter directly the `entity` to be deleted.

Comment: I wonder why `deleteById` is implemented with `delete(findById(id))` (as mentioned by @manish) and not with `delete(getReferenceById(id))`, which only loads a proxy object and not the whole graph with all dependent objects.